# Android studio get value from HashMap and assign to the class

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem which is I can get the value in the HashMap but I cannot send this value to my class. My error is `void com.paket.okulduyuru.Model.Duyuru.setPid(java.lang.String) on a null object reference`.

My setter method is:

```
public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
```

Activity:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

        duyuruRandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

        final HashMap<String, Object> duyuruMap = new HashMap<>();
        duyuruMap.put("pid",duyuruRandomKey);
        duyuruMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
        duyuruMap.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
        duyuruMap.put("context",duyuru_context);
        duyuruMap.put("title",duyuru_baslik);
        duyuruMap.put("bolum",duyuru_bolum);
        duyuruMap.put("yazar",duyuru_yazar);
        String pid = (String) duyuruMap.get("pid");
        duyuru.setPid(pid);
```

Comment: Please log and check if variable contains value or no

Comment: on a null object reference : this means the "duyuru" is null

Comment: i can print the value by using Toast but i cannot send value to class.I've tryed what you said but it's still null.

Comment: You should create new Duyuru before setPid.

Comment: It worked! but still i have a null error which is i can't get the value by using getPid method on another activity.